# Cutting the omer on Shabbos vs. building the Mishkan

Tags: shabbat, parashat-ki-tisa, vayakhel, maseches-rosh-hashana

Rashi to Shemos 32:21 quotes Rosh Hashanah 9a in which some Tannaim learn that the implication of specifying plowing and harvesting is to indicate that the only prohibition on Shabbos of plowing and harvesting are those that are optional, to exclude the omer which is obligatory.

Yet, the Mishkan is also obligatory (Shemos 25:1ff), and yet it does not override Shabbos (Rashi to Shemos 31:13 and 35:2). Why is there this distinction?

Comment: The mishkan has no fixed time, whereas the Omer does (Rambam Temidin 7:6 מצותו להקצר בלילה בליל ששה עשר)

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair enough. Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: I haven't checked if that's what's going on in the Gemara there. It also wouldn't be unexpected to just have some Asmakhtas about Omer on Shabbat to counter the Tzedukim.

Comment: @DoubleAA It sounds pretty clear in context that it's an actual derashah. "According to those who learn mosifin chol al kodesh elsewhere, what do they do with this passuk? They apply it to shemitah."